# SvelteKit server-side rendering: creating XML responses

Tags: sveltekit

How can one render XML, or other non-HTML output, with SvelteKit? I would like to use SvelteKit to render Google `sitemap.xml` and RSS feed for my blog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach which, IMHO, is the proper/cleanest.  You use a [server route](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server) aka API Route.

Create this directory hierarchy:

```
       /src/
┣      /src/routes/ 
┃ ┣    /src/routes/sitemap[sitemap].xml/ 
┃ ┃ ┗  /src/routes/sitemap[sitemap].xml/+server.js
```

And the contents
of your `+server.js` file is this

```
export async function GET ({ fetch, url, params }) {
  const { sitemap } = params
  
  //Add your logic to generated your XML here, maybe fetching an API
  //you can also use the sitemap var from params to process different sitemaps.
  const xmlOutput = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><sitemap></sitemap>`
  return new Response(String(xmlOutput))  
};
```

Comment: Thank you Hal. The previous answer predates the availability of server routes in SvelteKit.

Comment: Moved the correct answer mark.

Answer (score 1):

You would create an endpoint and define a different `Content-Type`:

```js
// example.xml.js
export async function get() {
  const xml = 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <field>This is an example</field>
</data>
`
  return {
    status: 200,
    body: xml,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
    }
  }
}
```

### alternative approach

If you want you could create a regular route where you can use Svelte components and hijack the rendering in the `handle` hook, but this approach is very fragile as simply changing the headers is not enough, the file will still be rendered will other fluff commonly associated with html pages surrounding it (like a body and head tag) so you would have to find a way to cut those out first.

```html
<!-- example.xml.svelte -->
<script>
  let value = 0
</script>
<data>
  <field>{value}</field>
</data>
```

```js
// hooks.js
export async function handle({ request, resolve }) {
    const response = await resolve(request)

    if (request.path.endsWith('.xml')) {        
        // Set the content type to xml
        response.headers["content-type"] = "application/xml"

        // remove whitespace
        response.body = response.body.replaceAll('\n','')
        response.body = response.body.replaceAll('\t','')

        // find the body tags if present
        const start = response.body.indexOf('<body>')
        const stop = response.body.indexOf('</body>')
        if (start > 0 && stop > 0) {
            // only show the content of the body
            response.body = response.body.substring(start + 6, stop)
        }
    }
    return { 
        ...response
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I assume Svelte components themselves cannot produce XML output and I need to bring in another template engine, like Handlebars?

Comment: I added an alternative using a regular route component, rather 'hacky' in my opinion though.

Comment: Yes, I agree - better to do it in a clean manner.

Comment: Moved the correct answer mark to the updated answer, as SvelteKit routing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

For the reference, I included a full example of generating sitemap.xml based on Stephane Vanraes answer.

Here is `routes/sitemap.xml.ts`:

```js
// sitemap.xml generation


// This sitemap is manually maintained and page paths included here one by one
const staticPages = [
    "",
    "about",
    "trading-view",
    "trading-view/backtesting",
    "community",
    "trading-view/exchanges",
    "trading-view/blockchains",
]


/***
 * Sitemap.xml HTTP GET endpoint
 *
 * For more information see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69523302/315168
 */
export async function get(page) {
  
  // SvelteKit page object does not include protocol, so assume HTTPS
  const proto = "https";

  // Generate the sitemap.xml file with string fiddling
  const fragments = [];
  for(let path of staticPages) {
    const fullUrl = `${proto}://${page.host}/${path}`;
    fragments.push(`<url><loc>${fullUrl}</loc></url>`);
  }

  // Build the XML for pages
  const urlXml = "".concat(...fragments);

  // See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps
  const xml =
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
   ${urlXml}
</urlset>`

  return {
    status: 200,
    body: xml,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
    }
  }
}
```